# Invoking make suddenly fails everywhere!

Tags: ros, compile, ros-groovy, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

after nearly 3 years of using the same (groovy) workspace on Ubuntu 12.04, yesterday as I was making a pkg (which was compiling fine), it started to give me weird errors in make. Even when the code is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
return (0);
}
```

Make produces the same error in all of my packages now, which has dumbfounded me. Can anyone suggest what's going on? Extremely long sheet follows:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/44e2ae289438777a21fa21146298a537

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231389/invoking-make-suddenly-fails-everywhere!/) by [Jorge_gr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26525/jorge_gr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like some of the operators that should be operating on boost types are missing.

This doesn't usually happen unless you did something to change your system, or you had some kind of disk failure. (and disk failure would probably show up as missing headers instead of corrupt headers).

Since the pieces involved in this are the compiler, boost, and your workspace, the first few things that come to mind are:

- Did you recently do an upgrade with `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` ?
- Did you recently upgrade your version of boost?
- Did you recently change something in /opt/ros ?
- Did you upgrade your version of gcc or install a new version of gcc recently?
- Did you recently add a header to your workspace with the same name as one of the boost headers?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jorge_gr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26525/jorge_gr/) on 2016-04-07**:
Well i update the system through the update manager regularly. Probably did it today, but only install through the main channel. If something was pushed upstream to the updater, shouldn't it have appeared to others as well? I'll scan for disk errors as well (it's a long shot though)

**Comment by [Jorge_gr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26525/jorge_gr/) on 2016-04-07**:
The problem is however, how to fix it! Any thoughts?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-07**:
I don't think there are very many users of Groovy these days, so even if this is a problem upstream you may be the only person experiencing it, or you may just be the first since you upgrade regularly. You can check the update history in /var/log/dpkg.log

**Comment by [Jorge_gr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26525/jorge_gr/) on 2016-04-08**:
Found the problem. For some reason stl_vector.h was corrupted. Replaced it and it works!